# How to rename all files in a directory from $filename into $Backupfilename

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a folder called, **evaluation**, located in, **/home/evaluation**, which contains this :

- Geography
- Math
- History
- English

How do I rename every file inside of this folder, into something like this :

- BackupGeography
- BackupMath
- BackupHistory
- BackupEnglish

---

**Here is what I have tried so far** :

```
for file in /home/evaluation/*
do
 mv "$file" "${file//Backup}"
done
```

But it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for file in /home/evaluation/*
do
 mv -i "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/Backup$(basename "$file")"
done
```

Explanation: `dirname` gets the directory name (e.g. `dirname /home/evaluation/Geography` prints "/home/evaluation"), and `basename` gets the file name without the path (e.g. `dirname /home/evaluation/Geography` prints "Geography"). So

```
... "$(dirname "$file")/Backup$(basename "$file")"
--> "/home/evaluation" + "/Backup" + "Geography"
--> "/home/evaluation/BackupGeography"
```

(Note: `+` is not a shell operator. At least, not like this. I'm just illustrating how it's parsed.)

Oh, and `mv -i` will ask what to do if there's a name conflict. Without the `-i`, it'll silently and irreversibly delete one of the conflicting files. Using `mv` for bulk moves without `-i` (or `-n`) always makes me nervous.

Comment: Thank you very much !! 
I was using a wrong regex :  ${string/substring/substitution}

Comment: @Finalmix6 There isn't really a way to do this with a substitution, because those'll replace the *first* occurrence of e.g. "/" with something else... but in this case you want to replace the *last* occurrence of "/" with "/Backup". Oh, and this feature doesn't use regex patterns, it uses glob (or "wildcard") patterns -- they're just similar enough to be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```sh
for file in /home/evaluation/*
do
 mv "$file" `dirname "$file"`/Backup`basename "$file"`
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help you provided !